# getelementbyid innertext not working

Tags: javascript, null, getelementbyid, innertext

Hi trying to use getelementbyid and innerText but its not working in any browser. When I open up the error console, I'm getting the following error message

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById("username").innerText = name')

This is my code:

```
<script>
alert("Using Javascript","");
var name = prompt("Please enter your name?", "");
var course = prompt("What course are you studying?", "");
document.getElementById("username").innerText = name;
document.getElementById("usercourse").innerText = course;
</script>
```

I don't know why I'm getting the null error.

Comment: You're probably running your script before the referred elements exist. Notice also, that Firefox doesn't support `innerText`, it's `textContent` in FF.

Comment: Make sure your web page have elements with **id** attribute

Comment: Where is your HTML. You should have Elements in your HTML with the id "username" and "usercourse" before referencing them...

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
document.getElementById("username").value = name;
document.getElementById("usercourse").value = course;
```

this works.

Answer (score 0):

Let me solve your problem by providing an answer before an explanation...

[Working Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/JddB6/1/)

HTML Change...

```
USERNAME:<label id="username"></label>
         <br>
USER COURSE:<label id="usercourse"></label>
```

Explanation: Now the HTML is very messy and im sure different ppl may do it in different ways, however what i wish to tell you is you cannot refer an element if it is not present....

getElementByID itself it self explanatory. Where in your question do you see the  the 2 id's that you are trying to refer, Hence the "null" error in console. Your HTML must have these 2 ID's. You can dynamically add elements from javascript but that is another issue.

Coming back to the solution.

innerText will not work with Mozilla as it is a Internet Explorer property. It does work on Chrome but not FF. Hence you should consider using

```
Node.textContent
```